# How can I set location to current working folder?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a powershell script located in "register" folder which I want to use to execute and exe file in "app" subfolder also located in "register" folder dynamically. Each time I run the script I get path not found error but I want the powershell to maintain the current working folder location so that it can work each time I copy to another drive.

Below is the review of my code

```
"cmd.exe /c PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden Start-Process '.\Register\App\record.exe'"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, you are running `cmd.exe` to run `powershell.exe` to run `record.exe`.  At the very least, the `cmd.exe /c` is unnecessary; just run PowerShell directly.

Comment: Can you present me a correct code. I have been trying to wrh this out fr several hours

Comment: After I ommited the cmd.exe, it seem it can't still locate the folder. Pls help me about this

Comment: @CHISecurity Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where your command is being executed, but I believe the surrounding double quotes are causing everything within to be treated as the executable file name instead of just `cmd.exe`.

If I open `Command Prompt` at `%UserProfile%` and copy `%SystemRoot%\system32\calc.exe` to `%UserProfile%\Register\App\record.exe`, then the following work for me:

- `Command Prompt` without surrounding double quotes: `cmd.exe /c PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden Start-Process '.\Register\App\record.exe'`
- `PowerShell` without surrounding double quotes: `PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden Start-Process '.\Register\App\record.exe'`

Both of these...

- `Command Prompt` with surrounding double quotes: `"cmd.exe /c PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden Start-Process '.\Register\App\record.exe'"`
- `PowerShell` with surrounding double quotes: `"PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden Start-Process '.\Register\App\record.exe'"`

...result in...

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Also, just in case it's not clear, you are attempting to run `cmd.exe` to run `powershell.exe` to run `record.exe`. At the very least, the `cmd.exe /c` is unnecessary; just run `PowerShell` directly.